# How to use map() with a function that has an argument?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I use

```
map(int, some_list)
```

while including the base = 2 argument for the int function like:

```
int('01010101', base = 2)
```

Comment: It's often done by adding a lambda like so: `map(lambda x: int(x,2), some_list)`

Comment: can be done as `map(functools.partial(int, base=2), some_list)`